# In The Vault, was the assistant bank manager acting benevolently?

Tags: the-vault

In the 2017 film, *[The Vault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vault_(film))*, a team of bank robbers hold up a bank, only to find that very little cash is on the premises. One of the hostages, Ed Maas, identifies himself as the assistant bank manager and offers to help the robbers access the greater sum of money in the vault in the basement, even giving them the steps to disable alarms, in return for them not hurting anyone. As this is a horror film, things aren't quite as simple as that, and the robbers are soon facing malevolent forces released from the eponymous vault.

> Two decades prior, a masked man "snapped" in the commission of a robbery in the bank, killing some hostages, and forcing other hostages to commit murder before burning the rest of them alive in the vault. He and the ghosts of the hostages start killing the contemporary robbers. Ultimately, it's revealed that Maas was also a ghost, one of the first deaths in the bank, shot in the head as he called the police to let them know the bank was being robbed.

What left me confused was whether Maas intended harm on the bank robbers, or if he was genuinely trying to get them to take the money and leave without further harming the hostages. And was Maas operating on his own, or as a puppet of the malevolent forces in the vault?